# Problema en código para insertar valores en vector

Tags: c#

Resulta que necesito diseñar un programa que lleve a cabo las siguientes acciones:

-Pedir un número entero al usuario.

A continuación, el programa pide tantos enteros como el número introducido previamente y los almacena en un vector.

A continuación el programa pide dos números enteros más: el primero corresponde a una posición y el segundo a un nuevo valor para insertar el vector.

Finalmente el programa ha de insertar el nuevo elemento al vector en la posición introducida. Si la posición introducida es negativa, el nuevo elemento se insertará en la primera posición del vector. Si el número introducido es mayor que las posibles posiciones de la lista, el nuevo elemento se insertará en la última posición del vector.

Me gustaría resolver los errores manteniendo la estructura del programa.
Todos los errores están marcados con comentarios pero básicamente se basa en crashes y en no retornar el mensaje en consola.
También he realizado dos elses al final del código ya que no sé si es lo mismo o cual es mejor para llegar a mi objetivo.
Sé que probablemente sería más fácil hacerlo con listas pero necesito hacerlo con vectores.

Adjunto el código:

```
using System;

namespace insert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int elements, position, change;
            Console.WriteLine("Insert total elements: ");
            elements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] numbers = new int[elements];
            for(int i = 0; i<elements; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert integer value: ");
                numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Insert position to insert element: ");
            position = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insert integer value to insert: ");
            change = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The final values for the array are: ");
            int[] result = Insert(numbers, change, position, elements);
            for (int i = 0; i <= elements; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result[i]);
            }
        }
        static int[] Insert(int[] numbers, int change, int position, int elements)
        {
            int[] newnumbers = new int[elements + 1];
            if(position < 0)
            {
                newnumbers[0] = change;
                for(int i = 1; i <= elements; i++)
                {
                    newnumbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
                }
            }
            else if (position > elements) //este apartado da error
            {
                newnumbers = numbers; //no sé si es así o newnumbers[elements + 1] = numbers[elements];
                newnumbers[elements] = change;
            }
            /*else //este apartado no da error pero tampoco resultado :c Manera fácil 
             {
                 newnumbers[elements + 1] = numbers[elements];
                 newnumbers[position - 1] = change;
             } */
            else //este apartado no da error pero tampoco resultado :c Manera difícil
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= elements; i++)
                {
                    if (i + 1 == position)
                    {
                        newnumbers[i] = change;
                        i--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newnumbers[i] = numbers[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            return newnumbers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por cada vez que insertas un nuevo valor en el vector el resto de valores se deben desplazar, Por que en tu pregunta solo dices que se deben reemplazar el nuevo valor, pero en tu código se nota que ademas de insertar estas tratando de desplazar, mover o correr el resto de los valores del vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código rectificado para tu método insertar sería así y te lo comento así puedes entender qué has hecho mal:

```
static int[] Insert(int[] numbers, int change, int position)
{
    // Aquí extraemos el tamaño del array por lo que es innecesario
    // pasar dicho valor como parámetro ya que es inherente al array.
    int elements = numbers.Length;
    // Como vamos a insertar, creamos un nuevo array con 1 elemento más
    int[] newnumbers = new int[elements + 1];
      
        
    if(position < 0)   // SI LA POSICIÓN ES MENOR QUE CERO
    {
        // El primer elemento del nuevo array será el que queremos insertar
        newnumbers[0] = change;
        // Luego se trata de copiar el array a partir de dicho elemento
        // por eso ponemos newnumbers[1+i]
        for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            newnumbers[1+i] = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    else if (position > elements)  // SI LA POSICIÓN SUPERA NUM DE ELEMENTOS
    {
        // En este caso hacemos una copia del array respetando la posición
        // del array original 
        for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            newnumbers[i] = numbers[i];
        }
        // Por último añadimos el elemento a insertar al final de nuestro array
        newnumbers[elements] = change;
    }
    else  // CUANDO LA POSICIÓN DE INSERCIÓN ES INTERIOR
    {
        // Creamos esta variable que nos marcará el índice de llenado
        int n=0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        {
            // Si nos topamos con el punto de insercción, hacemos
            // que nuestro elemento a insertar se añada al array
            if (i == position) 
            {
                newnumbers[n] = change; n++;
            }
            // Independientemente de si hemos ya o no insertado nuestro elemento
            // siempre tendremos que copiar el elemento en curso del array original
            newnumbers[n] = numbers[i];
            n++;
        }
    }
    // devolvemos el resultado.
    return newnumbers;
 }
```

En tu función principal, basta que cambies la forma en que llamas al método ya sin pasarle el número de elementos del array:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int elements, position, change;
    Console.Write("Insert total elements: ");
    elements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] numbers = new int[elements];
    for(int i = 0; i<elements; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.Write("Insert position to insert element: ");
    position = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Insert integer value to insert: ");
    change = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("The final values for the array are: ");
    int[] result = Insert(numbers, change, position);
    for (int i = 0; i <= elements; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(result[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perdona, ¿Qué ganas quitando el elements de los parametros de la función para luego crearla tú con el numbers.Length() pero el resto lo he entendido todo genial :)

Comment: Simplifica el código y te ahorras tener que calcularlo cada vez que quieres llamar al método. De esta forma queda encapsulado en el propio método que lo calcula basándose en el propio array y de esta forma se evita pasar un número de elementos que sea distinto al del array.